# How to lock View in position when ListView invades its territory

Tags: android, listview, view, scroll, android-linearlayout

As of right now I have a to-do list style app where there is an edittext and button and top and the user would add to the listview by putting input into it. Well if the user puts enough lines into the listview, the listview would be scrollable to see all of the items in it. The only problem is making sure that the button and Ad at the bottom of the screen don't go with it.

Basically, how would one lock some views with a scrollable feature above it?

This is how my xml looks if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/artport">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

<Button
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bAdd"
    android:contentDescription="@string/addItemContentDescription"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/addItemHint" />

</RelativeLayout>   

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">         

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bClearedList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad"
    android:text="Completed list" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXX"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</com.google.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make your root layout Relative and add to the list view the following: android:layout_above="@+id/name_of_the_bottom_relative_layout"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon your need, you could specify the height of the ListView. ListViews are by default scrollable. In your case, when you specify "wrap_content", it expands to occupy as much screen space as possible to display the list and then (since LinearLayout takes an "eldest child wins" approach), the remaining widgets below the ListView get hidden once the list becomes big enough. When you specify the height the ListView would occupy that size even if it's contents are not big enough to fill that size (thereby having some empty space).

Another approach would be to put the ListView within a LinearLayout and then the lower two buttons in another LinearLayout and specify the height of the lower container so that it always occupies that height and the by setting the height of the LinearLayout container that holds the ListView to "match_parent" you could make it occupy the remaining space.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! Playing around with the layout_weight helped my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the parameters of your ListView. Set layout_weight="1" and your ListView will get the remaining space.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    />
```